# Criando um dominio personalizado para os clientes como ICasei faz

Tags: php, nginx

Eu criei um sistema que gera um site para o cliente, como o `ICase`. Exemplo:

```
www.meusite.com.br/cliente1
www.meusite.com.br/cliente2
www.meusite.com.br/cliente3
www.meusite.com.br/cliente4
```

Exatamente como o `Icasei` faz

O Icasei tem a opção de gerar um dominio personalizado para o cliente. Exemplo:

```
www.ronaldocarol.com.br =>(pertence ao) www.meusite.com.br/cliente1
www.jessicaeleonardo.com.br =>(pertence ao) www.meusite.com.br/cliente2
```

Eu gostaria de saber como linkar esse dominio personalizado, ao "subdominio" do meu site?

Essa configuração eu faço no `nginx`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso não tem haver com o nginx, ao menos pode ser feito sem qualquer relação com o `nginx`.

Isso pode ser um apontamento de `CNAME` no DNS.

Tendo posse do `ronaldocarol.com.br` você cria um `CNAME` apontado para `www.meusite.com.br/cliente1`, isso será suficiente para exibir o conteúdo do `meusite.com.br/cliente1` quando acessar por `ronaldocarol.com.br`.

Dependendo do "servidor" DNS que usar, como o `DNS Made Easy` ou `CloudFlare`, existem APIs próprias para alterar o DNS de maneira automática.

Comment: Obrigado pelos esclarecimentos Inkeliz. Eu pensei que fosse algo por esse lado também. Obrigado mais uma vez.

Comment: poderia dar mais detalhes na sua resposta? como quais seriam estas apis?